# PUT request not appearing in allowed requests using ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, put, http-method

I'm not able make put request using ModelViewSet like in the documentation.
My views, serializers are as below

```
class PostsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PostsModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer
```

---

```
class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=PostsModel
        fields=('id','title', 'author', 'body')
```

PUT method is there in allowed methods as you can see in the picture.
[image]

And this is my posts.urls.py i.e., my app

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', PostsViewSet)


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include(router.urls))
    ]
```

and this is my root urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/posts', include('posts.urls')),
]
```

and in response for

```
http://localhost:8000/api/posts/1/
```

[image: Response]

Comment: of course `PUT` is not allowed here. `PUT` is used for updating an instance, so need to create an instance of posts. Then on that url `api/posts/<post_id>` you can `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE`. Fill the form and `POST` to create a new post

Comment: I have created posts, not able to update it..

Comment: No, this is a learning project so I have not created any permissions classes, all API's are open

Comment: Yeah, I have tried /api/posts/1, it says no matching urls in URL patterns

Comment: you can add `'url'` to your fields in serializer. Then you will get url of every post in response. You can just click on that.

Comment: I have updated the question, I get that response in POSTMAN

Comment: thats from the app

Comment: in project urls.py include urls of your app at `api/` then in `router.register` register your `PostViewSet` at `'posts'`

Comment: This is not the problem, I had done it the same way, I have updated the question with root urls also, sorry for that

Comment: try `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/1` without the trailing slash(No slash '\' in the end of the url).

    And are you sure that there is data with `id=1` ?

Comment: I had tried, not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/posts', include('posts.urls')),  # <-- Here
]
```

It should be:

```
path('api/posts/', include('posts.urls')),   # need to append slash after posts
```

Here, there is nothing wrong with `PUT` request, the problem is with routing itself. When you are hitting `/posts/1` its not being found by django(because the configuration was not correct).

Comment: It worked for me from POSTMAN however it's not showing in DRF page allowed requests, Thanks man:)

Comment: And I don't understand how the GET and POST requests were working.

Comment: probably you were requesting at `/api/posts`(without slash) for GET and POST.

Answer (score 0):

No need of trailing slash after id

change:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/posts/1/
```

to:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/posts/1
```

OR change URL pattern to:

```
path('api/posts/', include('posts.urls')),
```

and access the API using below url:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/posts/1/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right.
To see the PUT, PATCH and DELETE you need to access one specific entry. Because PUT, PATCH and DELETE are not bulk actions. So you should see PUT, DELETE when you access the endpoint `/api/posts/1/`. In the response you should see,

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
```